# Dimension of a complex vector space over real numbers

Tags: linear-algebra

What can be the dimension of vector space $\Bbb C^3(\Bbb R)$?
And is there a general term for any $\Bbb C^n(\Bbb R)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basis of CxCxC over R where C and R are the sets of all complex and real numbers respectively is {(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1),(i,0,0),(0,i,0),(0,0,i)}. So the dimension is 6.
Basically, C^n over R has a dimension of 2n.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).